# If $\liminf\, |a_n|=0.$ Does there exists a subsequence of $\{a_n\}$ which has finite sum?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, alternative-proof, limsup-and-liminf

If $\liminf\, |a_n|=0.$ Does there exists a subsequence of $\{a_n\}$  which has finite sum?

I tried to prove as follows:
Since $\liminf\, |a_n|=0,$ then we can find $n_1<n_2<n_3\ldots$ such that $|a_{n_{1}}|<\frac{1}{2},$  $|a_{n_{2}}|<\frac{1}{2^2},\ldots.$
Therefore,
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^N|a_{n_j}|<\sum_{j=1}^{N}\frac{1}{2^j}<1
\end{align}
This implies $\left\{\sum_{j=1}^Na_{n_j}\right\}$ is absolutely convergent, hence convergent. Is there another way to prove?

Comment: Wouldn't {0, anything, anything, anything, ....} have a $\lim \inf |a_n| = 0$ as $|a_0| = 0$?

Comment: @fleablood $\lim\inf\ne\inf$

Comment: no, there are talking about the limit of the infimum, so the tail terms n>k must have an infimum going towards zero

Comment: Not a duplicate, as this question asks specifically for a different proof than the one given in the answer there.

Comment: Your proof is good and I can't think of any simpler way.

Comment: @EricWofsey what's the difference?